# how to set a pattern in a variable using Z3Py

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm pretty new in Z3, but a thing that my problem could be resolved with it.
I have two variables A and B and two pattern like this:
pattern_1: 1010x11x
pattern_2: x0x01111 
where 1 and 0 are the bits zero and one, and x (dont care) cold be the bit 0 or 1.
I would like to use Z3Py for check if A with the pattern_1 and B with the pattern_2 can be true at the same time.
In this case if A = 10101111 and B = 10101111 than A and B cold be true ate the same time. 
Can anyone help me with this?? It is possible resolve this with Z3Py

Answer (score 1):

***revised answer after clarification***

Here's one way you could represent those constraints. There is an operation called `Extract` that can be applied to bit-vector terms. It is defined as follows:

`def Extract(high, low, a):
    """Create a Z3 bit-vector extraction expression."""`

where `high` is the high bit to be extracted, `low` is the low bit to be extracted, and `a` is the bitvector. This function represents the bits of `a` between `high` and `low`, inclusive.

Using the `Extract` function you can constrain each bit of whatever term you want to check so that it matches the pattern. For example, if the seventh bit of `D` must be a 1, then you can write `s.add(Extract(7, 7, D) == 1)`. Repeat this for each bit in a pattern that isn't an `x`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I have one more question. You know how I could represent this vector? Because with BitVec I can't put a value and with BitVecVal I have to put a constant.  How I can represent a vector with high, low and dont care ( not defined) value? I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: With BitVec this isn't possible just by using a single variable. Z3's type system defines the only legal values you can put into a BitVec to be 0 and 1. You would have to encode it either as individual constraints, as I explained, or as two separate BitVec variables -- one that represents whether a bit is "don't care" and one that represents which value (0 or 1) is set given that the bit isn't "don't care".